# How can ffmpeg decode video to jpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg

I am using ffmpeg to decode mp4 format video.

After calling avcodec_decode_video2 function, I got a decoded frame in AVPixelFormat.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P.

Is there a ffmpeg function that can convert the decoded frame into a jpeg file? I need to get the byte stream of the decoded jpeg images.

Answer (score -1):

Use [avcodec_encode_video2()](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__encoding.html#gaa2dc9e9ea2567ebb2801a08153c7306b) on a AVCodecContext initialized with the AVCodec return value from [avcodec_find_encoder](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__encoding.html#ga9f820c481615c3a02d0407bac0bdbf25)(`AV_CODEC_ID_JPEG` - since then renamed to `AV_CODEC_ID_MJPEG`). A full example of avcodec_encode_video2() can be found [here](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/decoding__encoding_8c-source.html).

Comment: there is no AV_CODEC_ID_JPEG exist in ffmpeg 6.0 source code right now.

Comment: It was renamed to AV_CODEC_ID_MJPEG.

Comment: The JPEG is not the same as the MJPEG. The latter miss Huffman tables in bitstream.

Comment: As far as I can see, FFmpeg's MJPEG encoder builds custom huffman tables, so although that may be true in some context, it's not true for FFmpeg. This can be disabled using `-huffman default`, but the default (..) value for this option is `-huffman optimal`.